# Ending then creating a table row in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to make it so that I can end a table row and then create a new one every three placed cells in a table within a react environment.

```
return (
      <div>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter item to be searched" onChange={(e)=>this.searchSpace(e)} />
        <table class="d">
        <tr>
        {items.map((route, index) => {
                return (
                       <td>
                        <Card style={{ width: '18rem' }}>
                          <Card.Body>
                            <Card.Title key={index}>{route.name}</Card.Title>
                            <Card.Subtitle className="mb-2 text-muted">Card Subtitle</Card.Subtitle>
                            <Card.Text>
                              Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of
                              the card's content.
                            </Card.Text>
                            <Link to={`/~twrigley/item/${route.id}`}> Check it out </Link>
                          </Card.Body>
                        </Card>
                        </td>
                        {index % 3 === 2 ? </tr> : &nbsp;}
                        {index % 3 === 2 ? <tr> : &nbsp;}
                    )
            })}
        </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    )
```

[Error][1]

Presently, it throws an error saying it doesn't know what the { token is
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qR0zq.png

Comment: You must only return a single root element or an array of elements from a `map` wrap your return in a `<React.Fragment></React.Fragment>` or `<></>` (the short hand) to supply a grouping root element that results in no extra HTML being rendered.

Comment: You cannot conditionally close JSX tags, you have to render the whole thing or none. It's actually a very good thing that we can't, old PHP code generating HTML that way is a nightmare to debug and maintain...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So React expects there to be one wrapping element.  You have your `{index % ...` outside of the `<td>` element block.

For example, this is valid:

```
return (
    <tr>
        {true && <span>example</span>}
    </tr>
)
```

This is not:

```
return (
    <tr>
    </tr>
    {true && <span>example</span>}
)
```

If you don't want to wrap an expression in an actual element you can do this:

```
return (
    <>
        {true && <span>example</span>}
    </>
)
```

BUT, that will not work here. Returning `</tr>` or `<tr>` is not how it works.  React isn't outputting a string of html like you would on the backend.  It remembers the DOM, and expects a returned block to always have an open and closing tag.

What you want is something that will format your `items` array first into an array of arrays.

I would do this:

```
const grouped = []
items.forEach((route, index) => {
    if (index % 3 === 0) {
        grouped.push([])
    }
    grouped[grouped.length - 1].push(route)
})
return (
  <div>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter item to be searched" onChange={(e)=>this.searchSpace(e)} />
    <table class="d">
    {grouped.map((groupOfItems) => {
        return (
        <tr>
        {groupOfItems.map((route, index) => {
            return (
                   <td>
                    <Card style={{ width: '18rem' }}>
                      <Card.Body>
                        <Card.Title key={index}>{route.name}</Card.Title>
                        <Card.Subtitle className="mb-2 text-muted">Card Subtitle</Card.Subtitle>
                        <Card.Text>
                          Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of
                          the card's content.
                        </Card.Text>
                        <Link to={`/~twrigley/item/${route.id}`}> Check it out </Link>
                      </Card.Body>
                    </Card>
                    </td>
                )
        })}
        </tr>
        )
    }
    </table>
  </div>
)
```

Comment: *expects a returned block to always have an open and closing tag* - Its actually more than just needed a open and close tag, it has to do with how JSX is transpiled. JSX translates to `React.createElement` calls, so there's no possible way to conditionally end an tag. Even if you return both start and end tags. i.e. `{true && <div>}{true && </div>}` will still break.